# Main.cpp(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv

I am testing this code, I installed OpenCV-3.0.0_2 But It gives an error :

Main.cpp(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Is it possible that this error is due to the version of openCV?

This is a portion of code to be test

```
//Include statements
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp" ///Here is the error

//Name spaces used
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //turn performance analysis functions on if testing = true
    bool testing=false;
    double t; //timing variable

    //load training image
    Mat object = imread ("C:/School/Image Processing/book.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (!object.data){
        cout<<"Can't open image";
        return -1;
    }
```

.
.
.
.
.

Comment: `#include` with `<...>` vs. `"..."` is treated differently. Why are you mixing those?

Comment: Have you included OpenCV header files ?

Comment: `nonfree` module has been moved to `xfeatures2d` module in OpenCV contrib. So you need to recompile OpenCV with contrib modules.